# Using Apache "echarts" code to render a chart as svg for offline use?

Tags: java, google-chrome, svg, render, echarts

Apologies, I'm not a programmer so this is a new world for me.

Is at all possible to pull element data from the java or css code on a website thats being used to generate a chart through apache echarts and convert it to an svg for later use?
Part of my job is animating charts and data and having access to the individual shapes, lines and numbers rather than just a "baked" .png would be invaluable for my work.

This is an example of the code in question

[image: 1]

I've asked a few web developers who couldn't help so if anyone has any ideas or can point me in the right direction I'd be extremely grateful.

Cheers.

I have yet to try anything as I'm pretty lost, as above several web developers have been unable to help so far.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think your first tag is wrong. You are talking about **JavaScript**, right?

I am not sure to fully understand your question, but if you want to get the **SVG** code behind a chart, you have to make sure that developers you work with do not use the **Canvas** API.

**Echarts** has two renderers: `canvas` and `svg`. See [Canvas vs. SVG - Best Practices - Handbook - Apache ECharts](https://apache.github.io/echarts-handbook/en/best-practices/canvas-vs-svg/#). If you want to use the **SVG renderer**, charts should be [initialized](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echarts.init) like this:

```js
let myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'), null, { renderer: 'svg' });
```

Now, to export your chart to SVG, you can:

- Configure the **toolbox** (see [`toolbox.feature.saveAsImage.type`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#toolbox.feature.saveAsImage.type)). A download button will appear in the top right corner of the main container.
- Copy/paste the code using **browser developer tools**.

Here is an example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Badacadabra/gvtz0745/)):

```js
let option = {
  toolbox: {
    feature: {
      saveAsImage: {
        type: 'svg' // <--- HERE
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['A', 'B', 'C']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [10, 20, 15],
      type: 'bar'
    }
  ]
};

let myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'), null, { renderer: 'svg' });
myChart.setOption(option);
```

```css
#main {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="main"></div>
```